# Populate a dropdown list from db

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an mvc 3 application with 2 tables in my entity framework.

PurchaseTable which was PurchaseID,PurchaseDate & ProductID I have another table called Product which contains ProductID and ProductName. creating a new view to insert a new purchase how do I change the textbox in the view for ProductID to be a dropdown bound by the ProductName in the Product table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Create a ViewModel:**

```
public class CreatePurchaseViewModel
{
   public Purchase Purchase { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Products { get; set; }
   public int SelectedProductId { get; set; }
}
```

**Setup the View with the ViewModel:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateProduct()
{
   var model = new CreatePurchaseViewModel
   {
      Products = repository.FindAllProducts().Select(x =>
              new SelectListItem
              {
                  Text = x.ProductName,
                  Value = x.ProductId
              }
   };

   return View(model);
}
```

**Then simply bind to the ViewModel and use the DropDownListFor HTML Helper:**

```
<! -- other code to bind to Purchase, and then: -->

<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedProductId, Model.Products) %>
```

Then when you submit the form, the `SelectedProductId` value in the model will be populated with the selected value from the dropdown list.

Comment: hmm so I need to create a repository to....man I am thinking of going back to asp.net as it seems to be so much easier to develop applications

Comment: no, you don't have to use a repository - use anything you want to get the products from the DB. Repository has nothing to do with MVC.

Comment: sorry for the late reply rpm. Thats seems to working a treat! Thanks for your assistance :)

Comment: @DiverDan You're not closing off your `new SelectListItem{})`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is easier than it looks. Simply create a list:

```
myDropDown = new SelectList(db.Products, "Product_ID", "ProductName", idSelected);
```

The first parameter is your table ("Products" from the Entity Model), the second is the "id" that will be returned when selecting from the list (i.e SelectedValue), the third is the "text" that will be displayed in the list and the last parameter is the currently selected item.

Assuming your model is called MyTablesDB, then:

```
MyTablesDB db = new MyTablesDB();
```

For example:

```
public SelectList GetPullDown(object idSelected) {
    myTablesDB myDB = new MyTablesDB();
    return new SelectList(myDB.Products, "Product_ID", "Product_Name", idSelected);
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: I am looking for a solution where I can add a dropdown list to a column jQuery DataTable, is there a similar solution to your answer that I can use in my program?