# Populating dropdown list in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have one table contaning

- country name and
- id

I want to populate in the dropdownlist ddl value as id and text as name.

I have reffered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827243/populate-a-dropdown-list-from-db)  but was unsuccessful

I am new in MVC. I want to know how  we can populate the data in dropdown list i tried google in most of the solution i got `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the view model but i am not able to get it in my code plz give me solution for this or is der any another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the SelectList with a ViewBag:
e.g.:

```
ViewBag.Countries = new SelectList(db.Countries.OrderBy(c => c.CountryName).ToList(), "CountryId", "CountryName", selectedValue != "" ? selectedValue : "AT");
```

And in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, ViewBag.Countries as SelectList)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Country, new SelectList(Model.DictionaryList, "Key", "Value"), "--Select Country--")
```